# Http Module - Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent

Tags: c#, iis, httphandler, httpmodule

I created a new caching layer.  The role is to serve pages from cache . if that page is not in cache it will let the actual request roll on .

my httpmodule is something like this

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <add type="myCacheModule.Class, myCacheMoldule" name="NewlyAddedmyCacheMoldule" />
      <add type="OtherModules1" name="OtherModules1" />
      <add type="OtherModules2" name="OtherModules2" />
 </modules>
```

my cache module has code something like this :

```
 private void ExecuteCacheLayer(HttpApplication context) {
      var httpContext = context.Context;
      var request = httpContext.Request;
      var response = httpContext.Response;
      if (CacheExists(request)) {
       var result = //method to get page from cache


       response.Write(result.ResponseBody);
       response.Flush();
       context.CompleteRequest();
      }
```

While the code executes fine, i am getting the following error

> Exception: System.Web.HttpException Message: Server cannot modify
>   cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.

I don't think there is any problem with my module, but i am thinking that since i am using response.flush, the other modules that get called are throwing this error.

Is there a way i can say that if some condition matches in the first module, do not execute any of the rest?

I know that there is no way to control the execution of HTTPModules and they get asynchronously executed in the order configured, i am trying to see if there is a solution for my problem.